# Passing a variable to jQuery scrollTo's duration

Tags: jquery, scrollto

The menu links on this project im working on triggers a custom function. The function takes two parameters. n is the index of the element clicked and p is the scrollTop to scroll to.  I want to change the duration of scrollTo based on how many 'slides' we have to scroll past.  1000ms per slide.  I set all indexes to start at 1 instead of 0.  Then I loop through all the menu list items and if it is the current slide, I store its index in x. return the absolute value of n - x... etc.. The math logs out fine.  The problem is that scrollTo is not accepting my variable. Any thoughts?

```
function calcScrollSpeed(n, p){
    var x = 1;
    var y;
    var pp = p + 'px';
    $('nav#left div ul li').each(function(i){
        var ii = 2;
        var iii = ii + i;
        if($(this).hasClass('current')) {
            x = iii;
        }
    });
    y = Math.abs(n - x);
    yy = y + '000';
    $.scrollTo(pp, yy);
    console.log(yy);
}
```

BTW

The reason I set ii to 2 is to account for the logo/ home link element not contained in the nav.  x starts at 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that yy is a string, nut a number

```
y = Math.abs(n - x);
yy = y + '000';
```

Try

```
 yy = yy*1000
```